# ADPCM codec info, mac converter, etc

Tags: converter, wav

So i'm dealing with the C4 engine right now, and its audio capabilities are pretty spartan. For compressed streams, the only codec it allows is ADPCM. Most of the information i can find on this codec is very dated and doesn't seem to be widely used (from what I can tell). Almost all of the converters deal with the container, not the codec (ie wav -> .xyz, not how it gets there).

Any tips on this are welcome.

I'm using a mac. I have boot camp but it would be a serious workflow cramp to have to use it just to convert audio.

Answer (score 1):

Sound Converter (available on the App Store) does adpcm encoding under a few formats for Mac.

Comment: looks like pretty lousy support from what I'm reading though. 10 bucks is cheap, but i'd like to know it's usable.


Comment: It has a few... quirks :) What container are you trying to output in? I could probably run a test...

Answer (score 1):

Shame afconvert only writes out CAFF ima4 files, otherwise it comes on the osx terminal..
I seem to remember a time when Windows Sound Recorder used to do adpcm files..